# Plane reprojection in post-process using homography matrix

Tags: 3d, linear-algebra, transformation, unreal-engine4, homography

Let's take a proxy problem - You're looking at some 3D scene. Now I replace the scene with its rendering done from your eyes position, so you don't see any difference. Then I replace the rendered image with a wall and projector. What I need is an image, that when projected on the wall will look exactly as if you were looking at the scene.

It looks like this:
[image: Here's my setup]
The left camera is the observer, the right one is projector.

My approach is to render the scene from observers location, then in the post process I sample rendered image to add distortion.

I have some proof of concept code that kind of works up to some offsets that I need to debug, but most of the computations is done in pixel shader so it's not the best solution.

After I did my initial version I read about homography matrices and it seems to be the right tool for my needs. If I understand it correctly I should be able to compute the homography matrix and then only multiply my screen space UV with that to get reprojected UVs.

Ufortunately most of the info about homography I could find relates to the case when I have 2 pictures of some object, pick by hand 4 corresponding point pairs and compute a matrix from that, but I don't have such points. Instead, I know the exact transforms of both views, their vertical and horizontal FOV and plane so I think that's all I need.

The perfect solution would be to have some transform that maps my image-space UVs in [0,1] range to correct UV for texture sampling. Did any of you saw similar solution?

**EDIT:**

I've made a screenshot from my POC implementation:
[image: Reprojected with ugly code]
I'm not sure it's 1:1 correct but it shows what I need. The rendering is distorted, but this distortion should cancel out when I project this image on the wall. Please take a look at the table top - it still look like rendered from the side and not from projector. When I project this image on the wall it should look like rendered from your eyes position.

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly - you have 1st person character, go to that room and then what? You need to see yourself from top right camera (like survelliance camera with appropriate effect?)

Comment: In fact I need to project some image on the wall, so you 'fell' like you were seeing a 3D scene through this wall. It has nothing to do with player itself, just a render to texture and adding projection distortion. Think of it as an entertainment installation targeted for one person at a time.

Comment: So, basically you are searching for this? https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?118-Render-Camera-view-to-texture

Comment: Maybe another approach could suit you ass well - it depends what you need to project to the player. When you wrote "seeing 3D scene through this wall" - do you really need to setup another camera? Maybe looking to another part of Scene through PostProcess volume will fullfil your requirements and moreover it will be much simplier and effective. (And if it is interactive, you only need to posses another controller and then back to your character)

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich I've got the 'render to texture' part already. The 2nd camera is there mainly for easier positioning - I take its transform to use but it doesn't draw anything so I could remove it and just use some matrix parameter. And I can't render from its POV because I need a correct perspective - so it looks fine for you when looking at the wall.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich I've added a screenshot from my messy pixel-shader POC implementation, does it makes more sense right now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118807/discussion-between-pavel-paja-halbich-and-kolenda).

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Comment: Hi @PavelPájaHalbich, sorry for delay. I've tested your workaround and it works for cases with single plane, unfortunately I need an explicit mapping to do the same for more planes/textures at once. In your solution the mapping happens during rendering, that's why I've asked about homography. I've got my own solution almost ready, when I fix all bugs I'll post it here. I'm still upvoting your answer, thank you for your help.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich I've described my current approach. I hope you'll understand why I was after this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.

In some of the articles about Homography I saw an equation to compute H matrix from known transformations of two viewports but couldn't get it to work, maybe I've misunderstood something or had my math wrong so I decided to try the 4-points approach, but how to get such points automatically?

Given, that I'm going to use this in post-processing stage of my rendering, thus operating mainly in screen-space I decided to map corners of my destination viewport to my source viewport.

From `Projector` transform I get the `forward direction` and rotate it by half of vertical and horizontal FOV. Combining positive and negative values I can get 4 vectors that correspond to 4 corners of my viewport, computed in World space.

Using `Projector` position as a start and 4 computed vectors as directions I can compute 4 intersections with my `Plane`. Those are World-space points, lying on my `Plane` that represents corners of `what is visible from projector`.

Having those 4 points I project them with `Observer` camera to its Screen-space.

The points I get here are the `Observer-screen-space` points and given that I've mapped entire viewport of `Projector` I can use typical `[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]` rectangle as a `Projector-screen-space points`.

This way I've got `four corresponding pairs of points` to use with my Homography.

### Homography

This was a bit trickier as I still don't fully understand the math here, but I've used this: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture16.pdf
article, on page 29 there's a matrix equation using `8x8` square matrix. The link may disappear but you can find the same equation in a lot of places, what's important is that I've used `8x8` version, but saw notations using `8x9` matrix.

Here's the screen:

[image]
In general it's a A*x=b notation where we know A and b and want to compute x.

For computations I've used `JacobiSVD` class from the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) library.

After I get resulting 8 floats I can build 3 row vectors of my matrix I'm looking for. First 3 values form first vector, another 3 values form 2nd vector, then we're left with only 2 values, so we append a 1.0f to get the last vector.

Let's call this matrix `H`.

### Pixel Shader

Having all those computations done per-frame the `Pixel shader` is really simple - we just need to transform screen-space `UV` vector with the `H` matrix (but in Homogeneous coordinates).

We get the u,v values and append 1.0 to get `[u,v,1.0]` then we multiply it with the `H` matrix. We've passed this matrix as a row vectors so we can dot product the `[u,v,1.0]` vector with 3 rows and sum up the results. This way we get a result like `[x,y,z]` but in fact it means a `[x/z,y/z]` 2D vector - this is our `UV` we were looking for. Now I just sample a texture with this UV and I'm done.

### Why is it better than Pavel approach?

I don't need a separate geometry rendering, which is especially slow in deferred rendering engines, like Unreal.

I can use few such textures at once, all on different planes. I can e.g. pass few alpha-masked and textured planes and decide which one I hit.

I can reproject a 3D side-by-side rendering to get reprojected side-by-side, by treating each half of a screen separately.

Answer (score 2):

From our [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118807/discussion-between-pavel-paja-halbich-and-kolenda), keystone correction is not implemented in UE. So I'would sugest following:

1. Create desired scene with **Observer** camera
2. Add **Plane** (**procedural**!) and **Main** camera somewhere on the screen, *Main* camera is looking on *plane*
3. Make *Main* camera as player's main camera
4. Create material as RenderTarget ([tutorial](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?118-Render-Camera-view-to-texture)) and set *Observer* camera to be source for that material.

Now you have setup that renders scene on *plane* and *player* will see that plane.

If you need to simulate keystone correction, you can change *Plane's* position or rotation. (You can bind that actions to your setup GUI etc.) And since it is **procedural**, you can change size (and shape) in vertical or horizontal manner. ([UE docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/BlueprintAPI/Components/ProceduralMesh/index.html))

Since you have one plane with constant UV's and you are changing it's shape, the result will be keystone efect on that plane, which (in case of correct plane settings) will lead to be inverse of keystone effect on HW projector thus generating correct image.

For settings all you need is to reset all settings on plane (rotation, position, scale, etc.) and set another *Material*, preferably with square(s) - something you can easilly see and which can help you to correctly modify the *Plane*. So it is just messing with projection plane.